# Laravel call internal API from controller using post and passing basic auth authorization to request

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8, laravel-routing

I am calling internal API route from controller but unable set headers using laravel 8

```
$request = Request::create('/api/login/', 'POST',['id' => '1']);
$request->headers->set('Authorization','Basic YWJjOjEyMw==');//not working

$response = Route::dispatch($request);

print_r($response);
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It doesn't make sense at all to make an api call from controller.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not working? Try doing `dd($request->headers->all());` before dispatching it and see if you can find your Authorization header. It should be there. Maybe it's something else that's failing. Maybe it should be `Bearer` instead of `Basic`?

Comment: Do not do this strange thing. Move code from controller to service and call service.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `Http` facade for that?

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$response = Http::withHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Basic ...'])->post('/api/login');

$json = $response->json();
$specific_field = $response->json('specific_field');
```

Comment: with Http facade unable to call internal API

Comment: Try using the full url  `post(url('/api/login/'))`

Comment: While calling my project via drive path working fine!. But while calling through php artisan serve URL getting timeout error

Answer (score 0):

if you want to sent an http request, try to use **Guzzle HTTP client**.

if it's not install in your Laravel project, install it via this command :

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

http get example :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$response = Http::get('http://example.com');

$response = Http::post('http://example.com/users', [
   'name' => 'Steve',
   'role' => 'Network Administrator',
]);
```

for more information visit Laravel doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client).

**note:** you should provide the full link. in my case in local and with the Laragon. I provide the following URL

```
 myproject.test/user/activity.
```

so in your case consider the port and the route url.it might be something like this:

```
localhost:8000/to/your/route
```